# VBA get number of column by it name

Tags: excel, vba

I have textboxes in userForm.
And for them I want to creat function that would find column(columns in a table have the same name as textboxes) by name. Then get information from this column and already known row and put it into textbox.

But I can't find how to create this function.
Mb some has already had the same case.

I've tried match function and find function of VBA, but has nothing worked out. Despite I get a number of needing row by find.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?  Please show what code you've tried.

Comment: ['.row'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) in conjunction with [`find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: @Cyril Hi I've tried something like this Set offersTableDescr = Worksheets("Opis ofert").ListObjects("OpisOfert")
someText = Me.Wymagania.Name
For cl = offersTableDescr.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
 If offersTableDescr.ListColumn(cl) = someText Then
 MsgBox ("exist")
 Else
 MsgBox ("nothing")
 End If
Next

Comment: Use the `Range.Find` method. If that hint doesn't help, please **edit your question** to improve it after you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DmitrijAntonov please edit your question to post the code you've tried; it is not an easy read in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim offersTableDescr As ListObject, cl As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set offersTableDescr = Worksheets("Opis ofert").ListObjects("OpisOfert")
    For Each cl In offersTableDescr.HeaderRowRange
        dict.Add cl.Value, cl.Column
    Next
    
    Dim someText As String
    someText = Me.Wymagania.Name
    If dict.exists(someText) Then
        MsgBox someText & " exist in column " & dict(someText)
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing"
    End If
    
End Sub
```